# Change value sign based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the sign of column `sum` by another column value `apple`. In other words, whenever it sees `apple`, the sum is in negative value. I thought I could do `np.where((ef.fruit == 'apple'), (-1 * ef.sum), ef.sum)` but it gave me an error. How can I overcome this?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':["ab3e3", "psdds2", "pas13", "ccdf2", "dsda1"],
        'fruit':["apple", "others", "organge", "watermelon", "apple"],
        'sum':[2, 3, 6, 8, 3]}

ef = pd.DataFrame(data)
ef

       id       fruit  sum
0   ab3e3       apple    2
1  psdds2      others    3
2   pas13     organge    6
3   ccdf2  watermelon    8
4   dsda1       apple    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not name your column with panda original function, if you do call it via `[]` not `.`

```
np.where((ef.fruit == 'apple'), (-1 * ef['sum']), ef['sum'])
Out[159]: array([-2,  3,  6,  8, -3], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to make a mask where `apple` corresponds to `-1` and the other values correspond to `1` and then multiple:

```
df['sum'] *= np.where(df['fruit'].eq('apple'), -1, 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       id       fruit  sum
0   ab3e3       apple   -2
1  psdds2      others    3
2   pas13     organge    6
3   ccdf2  watermelon    8
4   dsda1       apple   -3
```

Another solution would be to use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'apple', 'sum'] = -df['sum']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
ef['sum'] *= np.where(ef['fruit'].eq('apple'), -1, 1)
```

or with pandas [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing:

```
ef.loc[ef['fruit'].eq('apple'), 'sum'] *= -1
```

output:

```
       id       fruit  sum
0   ab3e3       apple   -2
1  psdds2      others    3
2   pas13     organge    6
3   ccdf2  watermelon    8
4   dsda1       apple   -3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ef.loc[ef["fruit"]=="apple", "sum"] *= -1
```

result:

```
       id       fruit  sum
0   ab3e3       apple   -2
1  psdds2      others    3
2   pas13     organge    6
3   ccdf2  watermelon    8
4   dsda1       apple   -3
```